# Why is my Custom Gutenberg Block broken upon save?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, jsx, wordpress-gutenberg

This is my first time creating a custom Gutenberg block. I have been able to successfully generate a couple of blocks. However when I create a post and use the block it works but when I exit and go back into the post I get this error:

> This block contains unexpected or invalid content

I did some research and I read that if the edit and save have inconsistent content it could cause this. I've been unable to find an inconsistency though and I could use some help. Below is the code that registers the block which does do as intended, but does not let me edit after creating the block the first time.

Help is appreciated!

```
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks;

const { 
    RichText, 
    InspectorControls, 
    ColorPalette,
    MediaUpload,
    RawHTML
} = wp.editor;

const { PanelBody, IconButton } = wp.components;

registerBlockType('myblog/call-to-action', {

    title: 'Call To Action',
    description: 'Block to generate a call to action',
    icon: 'align-full-width',
    category: 'widgets',

    //Custom Attributes
    attributes: {
        title: {
            type: 'string',
            source: 'html',
            selector: 'h2'
        },
        titleColor: {
            type: 'string',
            default: 'white'
        },
        backgroundColor: {
            type: 'string',
            default: 'blue'
        },
        body: {
            type: 'string',
            source: 'html',
            selector: 'p'
        }
    },
   //Built-in Functions
    edit({attributes, setAttributes}) {
        const{
            title,
            priceCard,
            titleColor,
            backgroundColor,
        } = attributes;

        //Custom Functions
        
        function onChangeTitle(newTitle) {
            setAttributes( { title: newTitle } );
        }

        function onChangePriceCard(newCard) {
            setAttributes( { priceCard: newCard } );
        }

        function onTitleColorChange(newColor){
            setAttributes( { titleColor: newColor } );
        }

        function onChangeBackgroundColor(newBackground) {
            setAttributes( { backgroundColor: newBackground })
        }

return ([
            <InspectorControls style={ { marginBottom: '40px' } }>
                <PanelBody title={ 'Headline Color' }>
                    <p><strong>Choose Title Color</strong></p>
                    <ColorPalette 
                        value={titleColor} 
                        onChange={onTitleColorChange} 
                    />
                </PanelBody>

                <PanelBody title={ 'Background Color' }>
                    <p><strong>Choose Background Color</strong></p>
                    <ColorPalette 
                        value={backgroundColor} 
                        onChange={onChangeBackgroundColor} 
                    />
                </PanelBody>
            </InspectorControls>,
            
            <div class="final-cta">
                <div style= { { backgroundColor:backgroundColor } } class="analysis">
                    <div class="custom-shape-divider-top-1606696223">
                        <svg data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1200 120" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                            <path d="M985.66,92.83C906.67,72,823.78,31,743.84,14.19c-82.26-17.34-168.06-16.33-250.45.39-57.84,11.73-114,31.07-172,41.86A600.21,600.21,0,0,1,0,27.35V120H1200V95.8C1132.19,118.92,1055.71,111.31,985.66,92.83Z" class="shape-fill"></path>
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                    <RichText 
                        key="editable"
                        tagName="h2"
                        placeholder="H2 Title" 
                        value= { title }
                        onChange= { onChangeTitle }
                        style= { { color: titleColor } }
                    />
                </div>
                <span class="price-card-cta-container">
                    <RichText 
                        key="editable"
                        tagName="p"
                        placeholder="Paste Shortcode" 
                        value= { priceCard }
                        onChange= { onChangePriceCard }
                    />
                </span>
            </div>
               
        ]);
    },

save({ attributes }) {
        const {
            title,
            priceCard,
            titleColor,
            backgroundColor,
        } = attributes;

        return (
            <div class="final-cta">
                <div style= { { backgroundColor:backgroundColor } } class="analysis">
                    <div class="custom-shape-divider-top-1606696223">
                        <svg data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1200 120" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                            <path d="M985.66,92.83C906.67,72,823.78,31,743.84,14.19c-82.26-17.34-168.06-16.33-250.45.39-57.84,11.73-114,31.07-172,41.86A600.21,600.21,0,0,1,0,27.35V120H1200V95.8C1132.19,118.92,1055.71,111.31,985.66,92.83Z" class="shape-fill"></path>
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                    <h2 style={ { color:titleColor } }>{title}</h2>
                </div>
                <span class="price-card-cta-container">
                    <RichText.Content tagName="p" value={priceCard} />
                </span>
            </div>
           
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't see an "edit" property in your block. You are skipping to a return. Is that allowed?

Comment: @JamesHamann I did leave out the edit on Stack Overflow accidentally good catch! (I have no idea how I left it out since I thought I C&P'd from my editor!) I have added the edit I currently have in my editor. With this "edit" property the problem has persisted. Just to reiterate, the edit property has existed in the actual code, and I forgot it on StackOverflow and have since added it to the code above. Thanks!

Comment: @user5854648 The attribute `priceCard` is missing from your attributes (typo maybe?) but is referenced in edit(). Issue could be that the `priceCard` attribute it was either added/removed in the updated block then however when the saved the post is reloaded, it is missing that attribute.

Comment: @S.Walsh you're absolutely right I failed to add this to my attributes. I had changed a name when I shifted direction on what the block would contain and never updated my attributes. I'll leave this question open if you'd like to submit an answer. Thanks for your eye!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute `priceCard` is missing from your attributes, eg:

```
registerBlockType('myblog/call-to-action', {
    ...
    //Custom Attributes
    attributes: {
        ...
        priceCard: { // is missing
            ... // set type, default etc..
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

The attribute was either added/removed in the updated block then when the saved post is reloaded, the attribute is missing causing the issue.

Also, when doing simple attribute updates, the custom functions section in your code can be removed in favor of using `setAttributes()` directly, eg:

```
<RichText
    key="editable"
    tagName="p"
    placeholder="Paste Shortcode"
    value={priceCard}
    onChange={(value) => setAttributes({ priceCard: value })} // attribute: value
/>
```

This will make your code easier to manage/troubleshoot.